# Autoencoder: How should hidden layer be used?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, autoencoder, generative-models, image

I'm building a variational autoencoder to generate faces. I'm using gray-scale images with the size 30x30. I started with a very simple model:

Input Layer, 900 nodes, values 0-1

Latent Space, 10 nodes (5 for mean, 5 for variance)

Output Layer, 900 nodes

The inputs of the latent space layer are normalized with Batch Normalisation and I use the sigmoid function on its outputs.

The model works okay and the input in the latent space layer controls things like background color. It produces images like these ones:

[image][image]

My problem is that whenever I add a hidden layer to the decoder and encoder, the images produced by the decoder will have the same shape, no matter what I input. When I change the input there is only noise that gets added. Here is are some image after I added the hidden layers:

[image][image][image]

The model was like this:

Input Layer, 900 nodes, values 0-1

Hidden Layer, 10 nodes

Latent Space, 10 nodes (5 for mean, 5 for variance)

Hidden Layer, 10 nodes

Output Layer, 900 nodes

The inputs of every layer are normalized with Batch Normalisation and I use the sigmoid function on the output of all layers apart from the input and the output layer.

Has someone an idea what I could change or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may be facing the "posterior collapse" problem, where the model ends up ignoring the latent variables, which become uninformative.

To understand the problem, you can check the articles:

- [Understanding Posterior Collapse in Generative Latent Variable Models](https://openreview.net/forum?id=r1xaVLUYuE) (ICLR workshop 2019)
- [The Usual Suspects? Reassessing Blame for VAE Posterior Collapse](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/dai20c/dai20c.pdf)(ICML'2020)
- [Don’t Blame the ELBO! A Linear VAE Perspective on Posterior Collapse](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2019/file/7e3315fe390974fcf25e44a9445bd821-Paper.pdf) (NeurIPS'2019).

One way to avoid it are $\delta$-VAEs (see [Preventing Posterior Collapse with delta-VAEs](https://openreview.net/forum?id=BJe0Gn0cY7)).